# Flutter web shared_preferences not available when tab is closed and reopened

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

**Flutter web now supports shared_preferences**. I have added `shared_preferences` to my flutter web app. 
My problem is when I set the preferences, say when I start the app, it works fine anywhere in the app but when I close the browser and start the app again and try to retrieve it, it returns nothing. How to I get this to work after closing and starting the app.

```
_showPref()async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setInt("myKey", 98);
}

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _showPref();
  }    

// then retrieve with the code
getPrefs(){
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();   
   int count = (prefs.getInt("myKey")??0);
   print(" 2. new prefs: $count");
}
```

Comment: Does shared_preferences work for you on Flutter Web?

Comment: I had the same thing happen.  shared_preferences works in the session, but when you close the session and reopen it, the shared_preference values are gone.  Share_preferences did not work locally or on the server in chrome

Answer (score 11):

`shared_preferences` plugin works as expected in production mode, just run `flutter build web` and serve files from `build/web` directory.

When app started on `web-server` device (i.e. with `flutter run --device web-server`) preferences may be lost because server started at arbitrary port. To fix it run flutter with option `--web-port` like

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 3344
```

There is no way to save preferences between sessions when app started on device `chrome` (command `flutter run -d chrome`). 
Every time `chrome` launched with randomized `user-data-dir` parameter, and preferences survive only page refresh but cleared after restart.

In source [code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart) it explained as:

> Using a tmp directory ensures that a new instance of chrome launches
>   allowing for the remote debug port to be enabled.