# Can I make SharedPreferences work correctly (either the debug or release version) when testing on chrome?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

When running a flutter app locally on chrome (`flutter run -d chrome` or `flutter run -d chrome --release`), it appears that information saved with SharedPreferences is lost when the app is shutdown and restarted. @Spatz pointed out (see comment in [Flutter web shared_preferences not available when tab is closed and reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503499/flutter-web-shared-preferences-not-available-when-tab-is-closed-and-reopened)) that comments in the code suggest that this is done to *allow the remote debug port be enabled* **when running in debug mode**. I found that the behavior is the same if running in release mode that, of course, doesn't need to worry about the debugger.

Here is the debug console output when running the debug version. The release version behaved identically.

```
...default_app> flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             25.1s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:57102/sEy2WI61D6M=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57102/sEy2WI61D6M=/ws

 Running with sound null safety

  To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
*** Initial userPreferences['counterKey'] = Not Available
userPreferences['counterKey'] = 1
userPreferences['counterKey'] = 2
userPreferences['counterKey'] = 3
# NOTE: Clicked the <reload> icon at this point.
Loading app from service worker.
*** Initial userPreferences['counterKey'] = 3
userPreferences['counterKey'] = 4
userPreferences['counterKey'] = 5
q

Application finished.

...default_app> flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             24.6s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:57508/JjuUJ3GODSg=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57508/JjuUJ3GODSg=/ws

 Running with sound null safety

  To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
*** Initial userPreferences['counterKey'] = Not Available
Application finished.
```

The code is mostly the default app but here it is in its entirety:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

late SharedPreferences userPreferences;
const String counterKey = 'counterKey';

void main() async {
  // Initialize shared preferences
  userPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  print("*** Initial userPreferences['counterKey'] = " + 
    (userPreferences.containsKey(counterKey)
      ? userPreferences.getInt(counterKey).toString()
      : 'Not Available')
    );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = userPreferences.getInt(counterKey) ?? 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    setState(() {
      _counter += 1;
    });
    userPreferences.setInt(counterKey, _counter);
    print("userPreferences['counterKey'] = $_counter");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```